# query that will get me the item name and item category name for all in orderID 12345

Tags: mysql, sql

[I need help in writing a query that will get me the item category name for all items in this list. Even if it is null like Item.categoryID it should still give me back the names.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36mpk.png)

The syntax is Select * FROM and then the names of the tables? Maybe? Or join them all into one table and return the names.

Comment: I was thinking SELECT FROM ITEM

Comment: You will need a JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `left outer join` at your disposal to the job done. left outer join basically get the data of the table on the left side of the join condition even if it does not find a match in the other table. 
for better understanding follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

[image]

lets suppose that you want to retrieve data from the green circle data even if you do not find a match do the following

```
select 
         table1.*
       , table2.*
from 
     table1 left join table2 on table1.columnname = table2.columnname
```

since you are more interested in getting categorynames I would suggest

```
select 
        cat.categoryname
      , item.name
from 
      category as  cat left join item as item on cat.categoryID = item.categoryID
group by cat.categoryname, item.name
```

This way you get all the category names and also items in those categories and find empty categories.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left join` since `category` column is nullable in `item`.

```
SELECT i.*, c.name FROM
item i left join category c
on i.categoryID = c.categoryID
group by i.categoryID
```